# Debug my code getting createHotwordData exception

Tags: android

Exception thrown by createHotwordData for model at: https://www.gstatic.com/android-search/hotword/x_google/6132a9a606e11d4fad2fe60739162a89/hotword.data

I simply got fed up with this exception , if try to debug my code many a times i got this and my app got crashed i am not able to understand what should i do i even googled a lot but could not find the fine solution , i am expecting you guys a solid link or answer from you 
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to start you app with debug mode not plugin the debug mode in the middle of the app

Comment: Ok..
if i initiate the app with the debug mode  it takes my app a slowed down towards the move on , otherwise i could not get this exception